# How to change imageButton touchable area to a cyrcle?

Tags: android, onclick, touch, imagebutton

I'm trying to implement an action on a circolar png image.
I'd like to get user tap only on the image area. At the moment I'm using imageButton, but the clickable area is a rectangle.

I'm wondering how to get touch only on image area, avoiding actions on all the rectangle. Is there a way to modify the shape of the bounding box?

Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the outline should do it. For example:

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
Outline mOutlineCircle = new Outline();
mOutlineCircle.setOval(0, 0, button.width, button.height);
button.setOutline(mOutlineCircle);
button.setClipToOutline(true);
```

Comment: thanks, but doesn't help, since my target is Android 4.2. Outline works only with Android L